# When switch screen using Bottom Nav Bar then i click on Back is showing black screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I use `Navigator.of(context).pop();` to go back, it shows a **black** screen, but this only happens when I navigate to the cart page using the bottom bar.

However, if I navigate to the cart page using `Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CartScreen()));` the back button works fine and no black screen shown.

Problem is when i switch tab using bottom bar then back button shows black screen other wise work fine.

any one please help me on this, I am searching many things but not working.

Cart Screen back button code ->

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
    child: Row(
    children: [
    IconButton(
    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
            onPressed: () {
             Navigator.of(context).pop();
           },
    ),
    const Text('My Cart'),
    ],
  ),
),
```

BottomNavitionbar.dart file- >

```
class NavigationMenuState extends State<NavigationMenu> {
  bool isBottomBarVisible = true;
  final PersistentTabController _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
  }

void _handleTabSelection() {
    setState(() {});
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
    bool isCartScreenActive = _controller.index == 2;
    return PersistentTabView(
        context,
        navBarHeight: 70,
        controller: _controller,
        hideNavigationBar: isCartScreenActive ? true : false,
        screens: [
          _buildScreenWithPadding(const HomePage()),
          _buildScreenWithPadding(Container(color: Colors.redAccent)),
          _buildScreenWithPadding(const CartScreen()),
          _buildScreenWithPadding(Container(color: Colors.orange)),
          _buildScreenWithPadding(Container(color: Colors.amber)),
        ],
        items: [
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Iconsax.home),
            title: 'Home',
            activeColorPrimary: Colors.redAccent,
            inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Iconsax.user),
            title: 'Account',
            activeColorPrimary: Colors.redAccent,
            inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Stack(
              children: [
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, size: 45, color: Colors.white,),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right: 5,
                  top: 5,
                  child: Container(
                    padding:  EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                          spreadRadius: 1,
                          blurRadius: 3,
                          offset: const Offset(0, 2),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: 15,
                      minHeight: 15,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      '${cart.itemCount}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            activeColorPrimary: Colors.redAccent,
            inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Iconsax.message_question),
            title: 'Help',
            activeColorPrimary: Colors.redAccent,
            inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Iconsax.calendar),
            title: 'Booking',
            activeColorPrimary: Colors.redAccent,
            inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ],
        confineInSafeArea: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        stateManagement: true,
        hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
        popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
        decoration: NavBarDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
              spreadRadius: 0.5,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: const Offset(0, 3),
            ),
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style15,
      );
  }

Widget _buildScreenWithPadding(Widget screen) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      child: screen,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. when there is no Scaffold on the flutter-page-stack, i mean if u r in the very first page & try to go back it shows error. *(when u push to a page then the page will be saved on the flutter-page-stack)  2. when a page doesn't have  Scaffold or Material then it also shows black screen.

Comment: I already have a Scaffold on my previous page but not working, how to solve this. This is only on my Bottom Bar switching issue

Comment: screen: [ _buildScreenWithPadding(Container(color: Colors.redAccent)), _buildScreenWithPadding(Container(color: Colors.orange)),
          _buildScreenWithPadding(Container(color: Colors.amber))] , these don't have any Scaffold

Comment: you mean like this " _buildScreenWithPadding(const Scaffold(body: CartScreen()))," is not working, can you help if you have a solution

Comment: u r declaring 5 screens, right ? now just make sure that each of these screen has Scaffold on the start..